# Laravel how to call a function in sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-4

I am working with Laravel and I am using a database in Sql Server. I need to execute a function that was do in Sql Server but I do not how to execute it.

The function in Sql Server is something that it:

```
Select dbo.functionName (848,95,37)
```

I try to execute it with this:

```
DB::connection('database')->select('Select dbo.functionName ?,?,?',array(848,95,37))
```

but Laravel return it: Cannot access empty property

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, i solved that like this:

```
DB::connection('database')->select('Select dbo.functionName (?,?,?) as result',array(848,95,37))
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this will work (Added parenthesis)

```
DB::connection('database')->select('Select dbo.functionName (?,?,?)',array(848,95,37))
```